# Ошибка Insert MySQL

Tags: mysql

хочу добавить запись:

```
INSERT INTO `user`(`login`, `password`, `email`, `phone`) VALUES ('danil', '159753bg', 'opa@yandex.ru', 89878562211)
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
#1264 - Out of range value for column 'phone' at row 1
```

Хотя в структуре таблицы я поставил длину int равное 11

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего у вас тип поля номер телефона указан как integer, и при попытке вставить телефон 89878562211 происходит выход за границы диапазона,

> Диапазон чисел со знаком: -2147483648 … 2147483647, без
>   знака(unsigned) – 0 … 4294967295

поменяйте тип поля на varchar и вставляйте

```
 INSERT INTO `user`(`login`, `password`, `email`, `phone`) VALUES ('danil', '159753bg', 'opa@yandex.ru', '89878562211')
```